# How to check whether inserted SD Card is write protected or not in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, read-write

Hi friends I am working on an application where I should check the file system of the SD card and also I need to check whether the SD card inserted is write protected or not. I was successful in getting the file system details as follows:

```
TCHAR volumeName[MAX_PATH + 1] = { 0 };
TCHAR fileSystemName[MAX_PATH + 1] = { 0 };
DWORD serialNumber = 0;
DWORD maxComponentLen = 0;
DWORD fileSystemFlags = 0;

LPCWSTR path = deviceData->m_strPath.utf16(); // deviceData gives me the path of the SD Card

// Get the file system details
if (GetVolumeInformation(
                         path,
                         volumeName,
                         ARRAYSIZE(volumeName),
                         &serialNumber,
                         &maxComponentLen,
                         &fileSystemFlags,
                         fileSystemName,
                         ARRAYSIZE(fileSystemName)))
            {
                newData.strFileSystem = QString::fromUtf16(fileSystemName);                
            }

 m_SDInfoList.append(newData); // m_SDInfoList is QList
```

With this approach I get to know whether the file system is FAT32 or NTFS. Now I want to achieve the write protected details. Is their a Qt API that can gimme whether the inserted SD Card is write protected or not??? Please help :)

**Update:**

This is what I did using QFileInfo:

```
QFileInfo fileInfo(deviceData->m_strPath);                    

if(!fileInfo.isWritable())
{                        
       newData.strStatus = "WriteProtect Enabled";
}
else
{
       newData.strStatus = "WriteProtect Disabled";
}
```

It always ends up giving me WriteProtect Disable even though I have set the write protected permission.

Comment: Are you looking for a Qt equivalent of the `GetVolumeInformation` Win32 function? Otherwise, the `FILE_READ_ONLY_VOLUME` flag in the flag set returned in `fileSystemFlags` should provide this information

Comment: @Andreas: Well as we know GetVolumeInformation is windows APi as I couldnt find any Qt API which can gimme the file format details. For now I want to know how can I get the write protect status via the fileSystemFlags?

Comment: You simply check whether `fileSystemFlags & FILE_READ_ONLY_VOLUME` equals 0 or not - if not, the flag is set, indicating a read only volume

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks. Since this is a Qt app, if I run it on MAC machine it will not gimme the write protect details I want. Isn't it? So is der a Qt API that can give write protect details?

Comment: You could check whether [QFileInfo.isWritable()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qfileinfo.html) works - use the root path / drive letter of the volume as the path when creating the `QFileInfo` object.

Comment: @Andreas: Please check the updated question now. I used QFileInfo but still not able to achieve result.

Comment: @Gojira -1 for using 'gimme' instead of give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you can't do that with Qt. You'll need to add custom code for each target platform.

However, you can simply try to create an empty file and then immediately delete it. If creating the file fails then the volume is likely read only (or it has ran out of free space, you'll need to check the error codes to be sure).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about how to do it in QT, but WinAPI provides you with GetVolumeInformation (http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetVolumeInformation.html) method (allows you to check weather drive is write protected or not), that returns the following flag:

```
/// <summary>
/// The specified volume is read-only.
/// </summary>
ReadOnlyVolume = 0x80000,
```